# I am getting Petalinux build warning for specific application

Tags: yocto, xilinx, petalinux

I am getting this warning when I build specific application, with petalinux:

WARNING: zynqRegs-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/zynqRegs contained in package zynqRegs requires libc.so.6()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_zynqRegs? [file-rdeps]

I added this line into zynqREgs.bb and still getting the Warning:
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libc.so.6"

Any idea what this means and how to resolve it?

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

PetaLinux support is best sought on the meta-xilinx mailing list.

https://lists.yoctoproject.org/listinfo/meta-xilinx

Philip